# Use argument in bash command in first part of a pipe

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

I want to have a simple function or alias in my `bashrc` that lists files with `ls` using all my favorite options and pipes the output to `more`.
Here is how it looks like

```bash
l() {
    ls -lh --color $1 | more 
}
```

However, when I call this function in a terminal with a wildcard argument, like `l *.txt`, the blob is resolved before it gets passed to my function. The result is, that I only get the first `txt` file displayed.

I am afraid that using a function is an overkill for what I want. Is there a way to do this without a function, with just a simple alias?

Comment: Why do you only pass the first argument to ls in your function?

Comment: `*.txt` is not the argument; it's a pattern that the shell *expands* to 1 or more arguments. `$1` only contains the first of them.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I didn't know that I could just pass all the resolved arguments with `$@`. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.txt` is not the argument; it's a pattern that could expand (depending on your shell settings) to 0 or more separate arguments. Your function only looks at the first of them.

Use `"$@"` instead of `"$1` to pass *all* arguments to `ls`.

```
l () {
    ls -lh --color "$@" | more
}
```

The alias would suffice if you weren't trying to pipe the output to `more`, as aliases don't take arguments.

```
alias l='ls -lh --color'
```

Comment: nitpicking: Aliases take arguments, but only at the end of the command. If you like overly-complicated solutions `alias l='sh -c "ls -lh --color \"\$@\" | more" sh'` would do the trick too :)

Comment: That's not the alias taking an argument; it's just the alias expansion continuing to precede the arguments on the command line just as the alias itself did.

Comment: Aliases do not take arguments. See [Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html). `There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, use a shell function (see Shell Functions).`

Comment: Serves me right to receive nitpicks right back. Chepner is right regarding terminology: aliases cannot use *real* arguments; although you can hack something together that feels like it.